# Drawing a line along the mouse movement

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to draw a line, which is following the mouse when the left mousebutton is pressed?

Comment: a straight line (from the first location clicked to wherever the mouse pointer is hovering at) or a directions line that draws the entire route taken by the mouse pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenLayers - a map library with lots of functions. There you can use Google Maps as data, and perform drawing on top of that.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html